# Como chamar uma procedure que usa um curso do tipo out oracle com C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle

Estou fazendo um teste para descobri como fazer uma chamada de uma procedure que tem este tipo de curso

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na procedure tenho isso:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE                "PTESTE" 
(
pcd_servicoagendado integer,
ptipo integer, -- 0 principal, 1 debitos
p_cursor out pkgcursor.t_cursor
).....
```

No meu projeto tenho:

```
namespace Generico.Aplicacao
{
    public class AtualizaAplicacao
    {
        private Contexto contexto;

        public void TesteConsultaSql()
        {
            string servico = "30864";
            string tipo = "0";

            var strQuery = "";
            strQuery += " PTESTE";
            strQuery += string.Format(" @pcd_servicoagendado = '{0}' , ", servico);
            strQuery += string.Format(" @ptipo = '{0}' ", tipo);


            using (contexto = new Contexto())
            {
                var retornoDataReader = contexto.ExecutaComandoComRetorno(strQuery);
            }

        }


    }

}
```

meu Repositório

```
    namespace Generico.Repositorio
    {
        public class Contexto : IDisposable
        {
            private readonly OracleConnection minhaConexao;

            public Contexto()
            {
                minhaConexao = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString);
                minhaConexao.Open();
            }

            public void ExecutaComando(string strQuery)
            {
                var cmdComando = new OracleCommand
                {
                    CommandText = strQuery,
                    CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                    Connection = minhaConexao
                };

                cmdComando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            public OracleDataReader ExecutaComandoComRetorno(string strQuery)
            {
   var cmdComando = new OracleCommand(strQuery, minhaConexao);
        cmdComando.Parameters.Add("P_CURSOR", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
        return cmdComando.ExecuteReader();
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                if (minhaConexao.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                    minhaConexao.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: se `OracleDataReader` implementa `IDataReader` seria só fazer um `while (retornoDataReader.Read()) { //retornoDataReader["coluna"].ToString(); }`, não ?!

Comment: @RovannLinhalis  problema e o erro que dar no retorno

Comment: qual erro ? acho que o command type tem que ser: `cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;` e não TEXT

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, veja a imagem, melhorei a pergunta

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, a procedure recebe 2 parametros, mais tem um tipo cursor que e preciso passar,

Comment: tentou: `cmdComando.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;` ?

Comment: entendi, talvez seja algo mais específico do oracle, aí não consigo te ajudar

Comment: Experimente chamar `ExecuteNonQuery` em vez de `ExecuteReader`